# Is there a fast way to see a site without the drupal admin elements?

Tags: 7, users

Once in a while various Drupal elements can be a real pain:

- The context menu covers the search menu & prevents me from clicking into the text field
- A co-worker is worried that the user is seeing things like 'Available Updates' notifications
- View/Edit tabs and action links are present in screenshots

The easy answer is to log out and view the page again, but that's a pain when you just want to do a very quick thing.

What is a quick, easy way to jump in/out of Drupal?

Comment: Use a second browser :)

Comment: That's simple, but not always easy.  If I have to re-create the page state (filling out a form, etc) it can be pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Yeah I was half kidding - cool script, I've bookmarked it

Answer (score 3):

I put together a simple javascriptlet that I can click on to show/hide most admin elements.  It is kind of a static solution (I'll need to update it periodically as new admin elements appear that need to be hidden), but it's simple.  Works with the Admin-Menu module too.

Just make a new bookmark and paste this into the 'url' field:

```
javascript:(function($){ if( $('html').data('drupal_clutter_hidden') ){ $('html').data('drupal_clutter_hidden', false); $('#block-search-form').css('z-index', ''); if( $('html').data('drupal_has_adv_toolbar') ){$('body').addClass( $('html').data('drupal_has_adv_toolbar') );$('#admin-menu').show();$('html').removeData('drupal_has_adv_toolbar');} else {$('body').css('padding-top', '64px'); $('#toolbar').show(); }$('.alpha-grid-toggle, .alpha-block-toggle,em.placeholder, #messages, .krumo-root, ul.tabs.primary, .region-inner > .tabs, .contextual-links-wrapper').show(); } else { $('html').data('drupal_clutter_hidden', true); $('#block-search-form').css('z-index', '100'); if( $('body').hasClass('admin-menu') ){var classes = $('body').hasClass('admin-menu-with-shortcuts') ? 'admin-menu admin-menu-with-shortcuts' : 'admin-menu';$('html').data('drupal_has_adv_toolbar', classes); $('body').removeClass( $('html').data('drupal_has_adv_toolbar') );$('#admin-menu').hide();} else {$('body').css('padding-top', '0'); $('#toolbar').hide(); }$('.alpha-grid-toggle, .alpha-block-toggle,em.placeholder, #messages, .krumo-root, ul.tabs.primary, .region-inner > .tabs, .contextual-links-wrapper').hide(); } }(jQuery));
```

Before:
[image]

After:[image]

Comment: I've added [a more readable version of this function to a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLLAZ/) in case anyone (or me, down the road) wants to tweek it.